# Use Umlauts in Modern CV

Tags: moderncv, unicode, font-encodings, cv

I'm trying to use the template compiled on [enter link description here](https://linuxundich.de/gnu-linux/bewerbungen-lebenslaufe-mit-latex-und-moderncv-gestalten/) webseite (to download `zip` file click [here](https://linuxundich.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/lebenslauf-anschreiben-moderncv-1.0.zip)) and I'm having trouble using German umlaut characters such as ä, ö, ü and also the ß.

In the preamble it does say

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

So I would expect this to work, but it doesn't.

Instead the compilation stops at the umlaut characters and wants me to replace them with workarounds such as writing `\"u` for `ü` (which I'd like to avoid).

My system setup is using TexShop, compiling with LaTeX on a 10.11.6 Macbook.

I would appreciate any ideas.

---

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Hans}{im Glueck}
\address{Gluecksstr. 13}{55444 City}{Deutschland \medskip}
\phone[mobile]{+49~(176)~111~2222} 
\email{hglueck@bsp.de}  

\begin{document}

\recipient{Max Mustermann AG}{Personalwesen \\ Hans-Beispiel-Strasse 2 \\ 55555 Beispielhausen}

\date{\today}
\opening{Sehr geehrter Damen und Herren,}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Gruessen,}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.

Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu.

\bigskip


\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your sample compiles fine for me when using umlauts. Are you sure your editor saves the file correctly encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Add `\usepackageT1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: The answer by @Bernard works well, only the German ss (ß) doesn't yet work, so I still have to use {\ss} there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess there is a little missunderstanding here.  Perhaps it results from TeXshop too, I do not know how this editor does encode the TeX files (special MAC code, `utf-8`, `ansi`, `latin9`, ...).

With Editor TeXnicCenter I can see the used encoding (see in the following image the red arrow).  If an document needs `utf-8`, but is stored with `ansi` one get the message showed in the image too. This message is pretty clear: the encoding of character `ß` is wrong.

[image: error messages in TeXnicCenter]

The following MWE compiles without errors after it is stored with encoding `utf-8`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % <=========================================
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext} % >================================= to generate german dummy text

\name{Hans}{im Glück}
\address{Glücksstraße 13}{55444 City}{Deutschland \medskip}
\phone[mobile]{+49~(176)~111~2222} 
\email{hglueck@bsp.de}  


\begin{document}

\recipient{Max Mustermann AG}{Personalwesen \\ Hans-Beispiel-Straße 2 \\ 55555 Beispielhausen}

\date{\today}
\opening{Sehr geehrter Damen und Herren,}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\makelettertitle

\blindtext

\bigskip

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

in `utf-8` encoding results in:

[image: resulting letter]